# Parsing Neo4J Cypher queries

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

i need to parse cypher queries into parse trees for an own project. i'd like to reuse existing code without having to write yet another parser. since neo4j moved to the scala parser and optimized, it is not possible to obtain a Query object from a String query in Java like before. I'm aware of cypher-dsl, but it does not accept a String query but only a query created "programmatically". Any idea of how to make use of the existing cypher query parser?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jexp/cypher-utils/blob/master/lib/cypher_utils.js, a JavaScript parser written by Michael Hunger. Is this helpful?

Comment: @KennyBastani good find! it's only a partial parser though.. not whole query language